# How do I use the drop down box from Flat UI Kit (free)?

Tags: css

I have managed to include Flat UI (free) CSS in my project which styled my buttons and text boxes (along with normal text) however I cannot manage to also style the drop down button which is shown on the [demo site](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/).

The problem is that if I add the class `select-block` (which is in the demo) to the `select` item in my HTML, the drop down isn't styled at all.

Comment: what is the exact problem ? any error occurred ?

Comment: Once I replicate what's on the website in terms of the drop down, the drop down on my site isn't styled. I'd like someone to show me the right implementation of that drop down style.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer designmodo website for free drop down tutorial.

**HTML**

```
<div id="switch">Hover me
    <ul id="switch-menu">
        <li><a id="ml">menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="en">menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#switch {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 13px 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#switch-menu {
    background: #3498db;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#switch-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: height 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#switch-menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    width: 120px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#switch:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
#switch:hover ul li {
    height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
}
#switch:hover ul li a:hover {
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #4aa3df;
}
```

take a look the example **http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/84bVm/**

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: @bluefeet Do want me to delete ?

Comment: I am suggesting that you expand on your answer because you have posted just a link.  If the link is ever not working then this is a useless answer to anyone.

Comment: @bluefeet how is now ?

Answer (score 1):

You have use the Selectpicker jQuery plugin that comes with Flat UI (which replaces the Bootstrap Selectpicker adding a couple more options) and initialize it in the following way:

```
$('select[name="myselect"]').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-primary',
    menuStyle: 'dropdown-inverse'
});
```

*(Replace `myselect` with the name of your select box.)*

Comment: Using the above code does display the menu in the correct way, but I can also still see the outline of the other element behind it. Do you know of a way to make the new element fit perfectly over the top of the old one, or make the old element disappear?